# Trouble debugging HTML dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

For the sake of debugging a toy inertial spaceship sim, I've been listing the currently active keys below the SVG window that the keys control. I decided to dynamically throw the data into a table to improve the appearance of the whole thing, but I somehow can't get the data into the actual td tags. Instead, the data keeps showing up OUTSIDE the table cells.

Here's the relevant code:

```
table, th, tr, td
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 400px;
}

.index
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.value
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```
<tr id="iostats">
  <td class="index">Keys:</td>
  <td class="value"></td>
</tr>
```

```
let iostats = document.getElementById( "iostats" );
```

All that is just prep code. The following bit of code is inside a timer callback:

```
  /* tmp will contain an array after this. */
var tmp = io.getState();

iostats.innerHTML =
  "<td class=\"index\">Keys:</td>" +
  "<td class=\"value\">" + 10 + "</td>";

for( var key in tmp )
{
  iostats.innerHTML += "<td class=\"value\">";
  iostats.innerHTML += " " + key + ":" + tmp[ key ];
  iostats.innerHTML += " </td>";
}
```

My expectation from this is that the key value, a colon, and the data value corresponding to that key value will be displayed INSIDE the data cell. Instead, as mentioned, they get displayed OUTSIDE the cell, shrinking all of the cells as a result.

Am I somehow *wrong* to expect statements inside a Javascript function to effectively be executed in the order that they appear? All of the code seems to run, just in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerHTML can not be in a state of unclosed tags, so this code

```
  iostats.innerHTML += "<td class=\"value\">";
  iostats.innerHTML += " " + key + ":" + tmp[ key ];
  iostats.innerHTML += " </td>";
```

First adds the `"<td class='value'>"`, then automatically closes it.  Then adds the text, then adds a closing tag.  To test this out, open a new tab, open your web inspector and type `document.body.innerHtml += "div"` into the console.  You'll notice in the web inspector a div element (with closing tag) has been added.

To fix it, just do it all at once:

```
iostats.innerHTML += "<td class='value'> " + key + ":" + tmp[ key ] + "</td>";
```

or

```
let addMe = "<td class='value'>"
 + " " + key + ":" + tmp[ key ]
 + " </td>"
iostats.innerHTML += addMe;
```

or if you want to get fancy

```
iostats.innerHTML += `<td class='value'>${key}:${tmp[key]}</td>`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Thinking about it, I can see WHY they choose to do this, but it never occurred to me to think of it as anything but a plain string.